# c library x86/x64 assembler

Tags: c, assembly, x86, 64-bit

Is there a C library for assembling a x86/x64 assembly string to opcodes?

Example code:

```
/* size_t assemble(char *string, int asm_flavor, char *out, size_t max_size); */

unsigned char bytes[32];
size_t size = assemble("xor eax, eax\n"
                       "inc eax\n"
                       "ret",
                       asm_x64, &bytes, 32);

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", bytes[i]);
}

/* Output: 31 C0 40 C3 */
```

I have looked at [asmpure](https://code.google.com/p/asmpure/), however it needs modifications to run on non-windows machines.

I actually both need an assembler and a disassembler, is there a library which provides both?

Comment: It's not going to happen if you need to use different vendors as you cross operating systems. GNU C may do the trick if you can use it across all of your environments. Have never liked in-line assembly in compiler code once I was out of college and saw the real world and haven't done it in years, but try http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: @Gilbert I don't need an *inline* assembler, I need a *runtime* assembler!

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Keystone](http://www.keystone-engine.org/) seems like a great choice now, however it didn't exist when I asked this question.

Answer (score 10):

There is a library that is seemingly a ghost; its existance is widely unknown:

XED (X86 Encoder Decoder)

Intel wrote it: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Xed/html/

It can be downloaded with Pin: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool-downloads

Comment: Now it is published as separate project: https://github.com/intelxed/xed

Answer (score 2):

Sure - you can use [llvm](http://llvm.org/). Strictly speaking, it's C++, but there are C interfaces. It will handle both the assembling and disassembling you're trying to do, too.

Comment: LLVM is a big set of libraries, and there are several tools that get built if you download/build the source tree, too.  You could look into those for example code for assembling/disassembling.

Comment: LLVM is a good idea indeed, but keep in mind that it's a full compiler, the process is taking c/c++ source code, converting it into intermediate representation, manipulating it for platform-free compiler optimizations, than converting it assembly (actually it also goes through some platform-free version first), performing some more optimizations based on platform capabilities, and only then spitting out machine code. If you want just the last part focus on llvm/lib/Target/X86 and on llvm/lib/MC

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/manual/lightning.html

Gnu Lightning is a C library which is designed to do exactly what you want. It uses a portable assembly language though, rather than x86 specific one. The portable assembly is compiled in run time to a machine specific one in a very straightforward manner.

As an added bonus, it is much smaller and simpler to start using than LLVM (which is rather big and cumbersome).

Comment: I have x86 assembly code that I need assembled, so I can't use that.

Answer (score 2):

You might want [libyasm](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/wiki/Libyasm) (the backend YASM uses). You can use the [frontends](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/tree/master/frontends) as examples (most particularly, [YASM's driver](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/blob/master/frontends/yasm/yasm.c)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using fasm.dll: http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=6239
Don't forget to write "use32" at the beginning of code if it's not in PE format.

Answer (score 0):

Write the assembly into its own file, and then call it from your C program using `extern`. You have to do a little bit of makefile trickery, but otherwise it's not so bad. 
Your assembly code has to follow C conventions, so it should look like

```
          global _myfunc 
_myfunc:  push ebp               ; create new stack frame for procedure 
          mov ebp,esp            ;
          sub esp,0x40           ; 64 bytes of local stack space 
          mov ebx,[ebp+8]        ; first parameter to function 
          ; some more code 
          leave                  ; return to C program's frame
          ret                    ; exit
```

To get at the contents of C variables, or to declare variables which C can access, you need only declare the names as GLOBAL or EXTERN. (Again, the names require leading underscores.) Thus, a C variable declared as int i can be accessed from assembler as

```
extern _i 
mov eax,[_i]
```

And to declare your own integer variable which C programs can access as extern int j, you do this (making sure you are assembling in the _DATA segment, if necessary):

```
    global _j 
_j        dd 0
```

Your C code should look like

```
extern void myasmfunc(variable a);

int main(void)
{
    myasmfunc(a);
}
```

Compile the files, then link them using

```
gcc mycfile.o myasmfile.o
```

Comment: You can also try [inline assembly](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) if you'd like

Comment: As said in the comments of my question, I don't need an inline assembler, I need a runtime assembler!

Comment: A very good answer to the wrong question. Useful for me, though :)