# How to call a C compiler through library instead of via system call?

Tags: gcc, assembly

In a project that I have been asked to revise, there is a segment of code that is tantamount to just generating a set of assembly instructions, writing them to a file, and then compiling it with the gcc compiler.

My question is, is there any way to link in a library that would do this work for me via an exposed API call? I need 1-1 equivalence to the following command:

gcc -m32 -c -o objfile generated_asm.asm -masm=intel

Comment: possible duplicate of [c library x86/x64 assembler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001094/c-library-x86-x64-assembler)

Comment: Succinctly, no.  The compiler is not an API that's callable from a program; it is a (rather large) program in its own right.  Using `system()` is the sane way to do the job.

Comment: I'm not actually loading and running the compiled code, this is for binary level analysis.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer an in-process library call?

Comment: It's faster and avoids the passing around of file names... idk, it seems proper (?)

Comment: Unless you can demonstrate, quantitatively, that running a separate process for this task makes your program noticeably slower than required, speed is a non-issue.

Comment: @AdamMiller It's only faster if it exists. If it doesn't exist, it isn't faster. You're perpetrating a logical fallacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do exactly that. You might `fork` the GCC compilation command. It is probably operating system specific, I'm supposing you are on Linux (or some other [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) system).

However, there are alternatives:

- using [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit) to generate x86 machine code in memory
- using [tinycc](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git) and its `libtcc` library (which can compile a string containing C or asm code; beware, the compiled machine code is slow since unoptimized)
- using a JIT library like [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), or [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)
- coding in a metaprogramming language like Common Lisp (e.g. [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)) or [MetaOcaml](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/MetaOCaml.html)

Also, you could simply fork a GCC compilation of some generated C file `genfoo.c` into a shared object (`gcc -Wall -O -fPIC genfoo.c -shared -o genfoo.so`) then dynamically loading with [dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) the `./genfoo.so` file (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12319329/841108))

PS. Next GCC 5.0 release will have a [JIT library](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT) (`libgccjit`).

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no, because Unix insisted we think of everything as text strings (including command lines).  And we all accepted Unix.

Technically GCC is just giant subroutine with a big parameter list.

The fact that you get to it though a text string is a stupid design decision we all made by dumping Multics  and/or LISP machines.  On these systems, subroutines (even big ones) are all called natively, and thus really compose.

With [Multics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics), the compiler *is* (well was, Multics is pretty dead) a subroutine you can call. (Yes, there was a command line interface that could also make that call, so people could invoke it).

Comment: I disagree with the "GCC is just giant subroutine with a big parameter list" phrase. There is no common data (or closed values) between GCC and the invoking process (since they are separate processes with separate address spaces)

Comment: Just goes to show what a clumsy parameter passing process Unix commands have.